# Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found warning and then google map service disconnent

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-api, google-play-services

In this map activity i derived the direction of two points but when this activity load then show the warning that googlecertificates class not found and disconnect the google api service

MapActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener, DirectionCallback  {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private Direction direction;
private String serverKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
private Double destination_lat,destination_long;
private LatLng origin;
private Button direc;
private User u;
private LatLng destination;
private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    destination_lat= getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("Latitude");
    destination_long= getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("Longtitude");

    origin = new LatLng(37.424,-122.084);
    destination = new LatLng(destination_lat,destination_long);
    Log.d(TAG,""+origin+" "+destination);


    direc = findViewById(R.id.direction);

    direc.setOnClickListener(this);

    ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

   /*SupportMapFragment myMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map,myMapFragment).commit();
    try{
        myMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
    }*/
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
   /* LatLng location = new LatLng(23.0225, 72.5714);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
    location();*/
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.direction) {
        location();
    }
}

private void location()
{
    Snackbar.make(direc, "Direction Requesting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
            .from(origin)
            .to(destination)
            .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
            .execute(this);
}


@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody)
{
    Snackbar.make(direc, "Success with status : " + direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (direction.isOK()) {
        Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));

        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = route.getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
        googleMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
        setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(route);

        direc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(direc, direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
    Snackbar.make(direc, t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(Route route) {
    LatLng southwest = route.getBound().getSouthwestCoordination().getCoordination();
    LatLng northeast = route.getBound().getNortheastCoordination().getCoordination();
    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
}
}
```

Manifests

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.geofirecollection">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UI.MapsActivity"

        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".UI.UserlistActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UI.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

App level Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.geofirecollection"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
// implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'

implementation 'uk.co.mgbramwell.geofire:geofire-android:0.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.2'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

//direction library
implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

when mapactivity load then show some warning

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
```

my google play service sdk is upgraded and i insert the right google api key but show this warning and then disconnect the google api service 
plesase give some suggestion

Comment: Have you (1) enabled billing on your project, (2) enabled the Directions API and the Maps SDK for Android, (3) added the correct API keys from your project, and (4) restricted them properly? Please double check these.